# Calculating Compliance by Current Date

Tags: custom-list

I am working with a SP 2010 list. The list is of systems that require an annual inspection. Users are able to enter their inspections to an SP Library, through an InfoPath form. That process sends me an alert that new inspections have been uploaded.

At that point I open the SP 2010 list. The list has columns that include 'Date of Inspection', 'Date of Next Inspection', 'Compliance'. I am currently performing the calculations outside of SP, using and excel spreadsheet, and then cutting and pasting that information back to the SP 2010 list, which queries the data and displays it on a user InfoPath form that allows the user to know whether a system is 'Compliant' or 'Noncompliant' with the annual inspection requirement, based on the current date.

I am looking for a way to perform the calculations in the SP 2010 list, rather than in the excel spreadsheet. Is there a process that would allow me to have an SP 2010 list perform and display the compliance calculation, rather than having to export/import the data in and out for the calculation?

Comment: Is all of the data needed for the calculation in the list? If so, you can just use calculated fields.

Comment: Compliance is based off a comparison of the date of last inspection compared to 'Today'. The device is noncompliant if not inspected every 365 days. All indications are the current date ('Today') cannot be used in a calculated field. I am looking for a way to have the database list look at each line item 'Date of Last Inspection' field every 24 hours; and, where the it is more than 364 days since the last inspection the database changes the status field from 'Compliant' to 'Noncompliant'.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a calculated field. In this case, you want to say "If Today minus Date of Last Inspection is greater than 364, then Status equals Noncompliant, else Status equals Compliant. You can see the syntax and available calculations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx).

Create a calculated field called Status and set the formula to:

```
=IF([Today]-[Date of Last Inspection]>=364,"Noncompliant","Compliant")
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this matter. I have read all over the intersweb that Today and Me cannot be used in SP list calculated columns. When I try your formula I get an error message that states "Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me." Please advise.

Comment: I forgot that. There's a workaround. Create a column named `Today`, create your calculated field with the formula I provided, then delete `Today` column. You'll have to recreate the fake column in the future if you want to change this formula.

Comment: Nope, still not working.

Comment: Nope, still not working.  I have a column for: Date of Last Inspection (Date Only type column); Today (Date Only type with Today's Date button chosen); Status (Calculated Column with =IF(Today-[Date of Last Inspection]>=364,"Noncompliant","Compliant"). All that gets me "Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me". Please advise, thank you.

Comment: Trying putting the square brackets around `[Today]`

Comment: I enter the formula exactly as you've written it. The system reformats it , and removes the brackets when I try to lock it in; then kicks out the error message.

Comment: I feel like I'm so close.  I've been able to get 'Noncompliant' to auto-populate in the Compliance Status column. Here's a recap.

Comment: Col 1=Dat of Last; Col 2=Plus 1 Yr (Number type column, with 364 in default; Col 3=Compliance Status (calculated column, with =IF([Plus One Year]+[Date of Last Inspection]>364,"Noncompliant","Compliant"). No matter the date I enter in Col 1, Compliance Status column is always 'Noncompliant'.

Comment: That won't work. `[Plus One Year]` will always equal 364.

Comment: You could easily create a view that shows only those in compliance and another for those that are noncompliant. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: That is a possible solution. What I am unsure of now is the formula. Currently, the compliance column shows all compliant or all noncompliant , when the dates provided should force half to show compliant and half noncompliant. There is still something not quite right about the formula(s), and I can't figure out what. Is it the default value in the 'one year' column, Which I currently have as just the number '364'. Should this be something else?

Comment: No, the formula won't work without making `Today` dynamic. I don't know why that's not working for you. That's why I asked if view was an option.

Comment: I keep getting the same error message "Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me. "  The system won't even let me lock in the formula you provided. I'm displaying the data by way of InfoPath form, and the user needs to be able to see one list that shows by 'Compliant' and 'Noncompliant' line items together.

Comment: Victory!!!

I changed the label of the 'Today' column to 'Current', and I set the Default Value to 'Today'. This allowed me to use the following formula in the calculated field Compliance Status column: =IF(Current-[Date of Last Inspection]<=365,"Compliant","Noncompliant").

It took  two weeks, but I finally got it. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: When in Excel, in the event no report was submitted I would simply manually enter 'No Report Submitted' in the SP list column of 'Date of Last Inspected'. Now that there is a SP calculated field column, if I type any text into the 'Date of Last Inspected' column, the process sees this as a error and generates '#VALUE' in the Compliance column. Is there a way to edit the IF statement below to include determining if the 'Date of Last Inspected' field is blank, and if so make Compliance column 'Noncompliant'? =IF(Current-[Date of Last Inspection]<=365,"Compliant","Noncompliant").

Comment: Is `Date of Last Inspected` a text field or a date?

Comment: The Date of Last Inspected SP column content types is 'Date'.

Comment: Like this? `=IF(ISBLANK([Date of Last Inspected]),"Noncompliant",IF(Current-[Date of Last Inspection]<=365,"Compliant","Noncompliant"))`

Comment: Perfect! Now, how about if the Date of Last Inspection column (still being a Date type field),

Comment: Perfect! Now, how about if the Date of Last Inspection column (still being a Date type field), contains the text "No Report Submitted", can a similar formula to the ISBLANK version be written that will produce "Noncompliant"?

Comment: Dates can't hold text.

Comment: Are you just SP, do you also do InfoPath? Can I create a rule in InfoPath that says after query of SP list if Date of Inspection field is/remains blank add 'No Report Submitted'?

Comment: Okay, first, yes... you can do that.  Second... you're really supposed to try stuff on your own before asking us how to do it.

Comment: But if that's what you want, why not just `=IF(ISBLANK([Date of Last Inspected]),"No Report Submitted",IF(Current-[Date of Last Inspection]<=365,"Compliant","Noncompliant"))`

Comment: That's like asking a 3rd grader to work out an algebra question. I didn't know the site required us to toil in adversity before seeking assistance. To be clear, before May I'd never done any of this. I've spent countless hours since on trial & error to get me to this point - as a dislocate my shoulder patting myself on the back with pride. This question is about whether I can place text in a date field, which I believe you said 'No'. Currently, the query leaves blank fields in my InfoPath form. I'd rather have is leave 'No Report Submitted' where no date is entered in the SP list date column.

Comment: You cannot place text into a SharePoint date field. (If you tried that, you'd see it didn't save.) Pretty sure you can't place text into a date field in InfoPath. (You could try that yourself too.) You CAN create a text box in InfoPath and a rule to set the value of the text box to either the date or "No Report Submitted" depending on whether there's a date entered. And yes, the site does expect you to get as far as you can on your own. Your original question was fine. But later on, you could have googled to find out how to check if a field is blank, or the format of the if-else statement.

Comment: You have been very kind, and patient with my ignorance, and I would not have resolved my issues without your assist; for that I thank you. I'll dissolve back into my toil. HAPPY HOLIDAYS!

Comment: You could create a new calculated field, returned as text. `=IF(ISBLANK([Date of Last Inspected]),"No Report Submitted",[Date of Last Inspected])`